# how to read raw from any device ( ex. Keyboard ) in C

Tags: c, device, share

im wondering that i could share my keyboard device to another host by using ethernet protocol,
but in order to do that, i must know how to read the 'keyboard input from port' from my 'source host', after that i have to build some /dev/ on 'remote host' by ethernet packet which contain 'keyboard input' from 'source host'.

the real question is, how to identify and read the input device on 'source host' (perhaps in C language)?

thx in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, it already [exists](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/). Otherwise use [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) or [Slang](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/).

Comment: Well actually it's USB over IP, but it has the same effect.

Comment: well its read usb structure, now how about vga or PCI bus ?, how come could i read this device directly, is 'PCI bus' has similiar structure like usb structure ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to tunnel keyboard input over the network? That's how I interpretted the original question. If you want to tunnel a PCI device over the network, that's another question.

Comment: thats why i need to know how to 'identify' and 'read' the device, can u feel me ?

Answer (score 0):

GNU screen sounds like the straightforward answer to *sharing* a session.